# Change Google Translate widget height width

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I have included Google widget in my page, but I want to increase the height and width of the dropdown box. How can I change this with CSS?

Here is my Google Translate widget code:

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
      }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your styles as below for the class `goog-te-combo`, and include this in your css.

Sample working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9nvuf043/1/).

```
.goog-te-combo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: do you know , how to change the font size of the above google widget , i tried with font-size: 90px; in same css that you mentioned but fonts are looking same.

Comment: actually when i increase the size  with css class then widget box size increased but fonts are having the same size , that looks little ugly , widget box is  bigger in size with smalll fonts.

Comment: I tried this `.goog-te-combo { width: 200px; height: 50px; font-size: 20px; }` and it worked

Comment: updated the sample working code url as well.

Comment: @owmyadharGourishetty its working in jsfiddle but when I used it in my web pages then its not working on any of browser but box size is working , quite strange.

Comment: try `font-size: 20px !important`

Comment: Yes i did the same , i am trying with 20px only.but same code in fiddle working and not working on browser ...:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234579/discussion-between-vim-and-sowmyadhar-gourishetty).